# How to display million results in a fastest way PHP MYSql

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I have a question, how do you display a million results in front-end HTML/PHP/MYSQL in a fastest way? I have 2 tables: Table 2 a million per month and Table 3 consists a thousand of data's per month. Now, how am I going to display all results in a fastest way of retrieving a data in mysql? Here's my sample query when retrieving a data:

```
SELECT `r`.`ID`, `r`.`CurrentMonth`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `s`.`NameEmployee` SEPARATOR '; ') AS `Name`, `s`.`BA` as `Area`, `r`.`PresRdgDate` as `ReadingDate`, `r`.`PresRemarks`,
time_format(concat(MIN(`r`.`ReadingTime`),'00'),'%H:%i:%s') AS `StartReading`,
time_format(concat(MAX(`r`.`ReadingTime`),'00'),'%H:%i:%s') AS `EndReading`,
TIMEDIFF(time_format(concat(MAX(`r`.`ReadingTime`),'00'),'%H:%i:%s'), time_format(concat(MIN(`r`.`ReadingTime`),'00'),'%H:%i:%s')) AS `TotalRdgTime`,
COUNT(`r`.`AccountNum`) AS `TotalRdgPerMRU`
FROM `table2` as `r`
LEFT JOIN `table3` as `s` ON `s`.`ID` = `r`.`ID`
WHERE (`r`.`CurrentMonth` >= '01' AND `r`.`CurrentMonth` <= '02')
AND `r`.`ID` LIKE '%%'
GROUP BY `r`.`ID`;
```

I am using an ajax to send the request from a user and pass to php, I also using a pagination to separate the display results by 10, so it won't load all data's in one page. When I am generating a search , it gives me a result within 5 mins, and when I click the next page, another 5 mins of waiting. Please suggest what is the better/best way to retrieve a data in MYSql and display the results not more than 5 mins. Plus I need to add a sort per column in front-end, also it will cause a slow display of the data in front-end.

Comment: try to apply caching

Comment: A thousand? Or a million?

Comment: table 2 consists of million data per month, table 3 a thousands per month Sir Jay

Comment: really negative???

Comment: use LIMIT to fetch only a certain number at a time, ie limit 1000, then page two: LIMIT 1000 START 1001 and onwards.

Answer (score 0):

You said you are using pagination by displaying 10 results per page. But, you did not use any limit and offset value in your query.

Use "LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0" at the end of your query for 1st page, "LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10" for 2nd page, "LIMIT 10 OFFSET 20" for 3rd page and so on....